# Using Original m-BOX with Garageband and OS 10.6.8

Tags: audio-interfaces

I installed drivers as suggested. Computer/Garageband is recognizing the mBox and I am getting a signal, but it's only mono. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running things in to both inputs.  The inputs are mono.  If you are using a stereo line, you will need to break out the right and left inputs separately.